# Is there a way to make spaces and/or tabs visible on git log -p?

Tags: git, tabs, patch, spaces

My text editor is set to make tabs visible (i.e. '>...' but with a different color than the rest of the text) and distinguish them from spaces. But when I do `git log -p` there's no such distinction. Is there any way to configure git to do a similar thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way, at lease I didn't find it. But you probably can use your editor as a pager. This how I'd do it with my `vim`:

```
git log -p | vim -c "syntax on" -c "set ft=diff" -
```